# Sort on different properties

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a document, lets say it has properties

```
 "title": {
    "type": "string"
  },
  "author": {
    "type": "string"
  }
```

Normally when I search I want to have higher score on titles
But if I search for an author I want to get higher score on the author property.

Leta say I search Inferno.

I get (which I want)

```
 1. Inferno
 2. Fernando
 3. furnished.
```

But now I enter Dan Brown
I want to get the same result, not

```
Danish meal
DanSomething
Dan..
```

I cant know before I search if I am searching for an author or a title.
Do you have any Ideas how I would implement this?

Comment: What query do you use??

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way of achieving this is by boosting the query on the `author` field so that if there's an author match it'll appear below other matches on the `title` field.

For instance, you can try like this:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "query_string": {
            "query": "Dan Brown",
            "fields": [
              "title"
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "query_string": {
            "query": "Dan Brown",
            "boost": 2,
            "fields": [
              "author"
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

In the above query, we gave a boost of 2 to results that match `Dan Brown` as an author.

Note that this just gives you a bootstrap, it's definitely not the end of the story. In order to get perfect results, it might be needed to create one or more custom analyzers in order to properly index the tokens you need to search for. But this should get you going.